# Calling the function again using a button and Jquery (Dropdown)

Tags: jquery, function, onchange

I have a dropdown:

```
<select onchange=\"getInfo(this.value);\">"
```

**Jquery**:

```
function getInfo(user_id)
{
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://website.com",
       data: "user_id=" + user_id,
       success: function(result){
         $("#TargetInfo").html(result);
       }
     });         
};
```

To rerun some info about a user.

I want to have a button or something like that (**Using Jquery**) to reload the infomation again when I update the database (To call again the function **getInfo**). The user has to stay selected in the dropdown!

**NB:** At this moment I choose another user, then I go back the first one.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @artm I don't know yet how to start. This is above my knowledge.

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: @Nicholas ok. Wait a moment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an ID to the select box:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="getInfo(this.value);">
```

Add the button like this

```
<input type="button" onClick="reloadSelectedUser();">
```

and a JS function:

```
function reloadSelectedUser()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var usr = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    getInfo(usr);
}
```